# Casio Calculator Programming

Tags: c, sdk, calculator, basic

I am planning to buy a CASIO FX-9860GII for school, but I am really interested in programming for it.

I looked everywhere on the internet but could not find anything.
Is it possible to create programs for it in languages like C or maybe Java and how do you do it?

Comment: I would expect that it uses some assembly language (at least my TI did years ago), or some ugly variant of Basic. Both are not pretty nice to work with.

Comment: "I looked everywhere on the internet but could not find anything" -- seriously? Two clicks and I got at the User Manual at casio.com. "C or maybe Java", seriously? It's still a calculator. Maybe you should be looking for a laptop (or possibly for a keyboard).

Comment: We can't use a laptop in class. I am in high school so it's no option. Edit: I wanted to program for it because of some algorithms etc. maybe that could be helpful

Comment: @Rad Lexus, it does in fact support C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These calculators come with a [BASIC-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) interpretator, so you'd probably want to look into that. Recently, a C compiler was released, so you can program in both languages.

[Here](http://edu.casio.com/products/sdk/pdf/fx9860g_sdk_starters_guide.pdf), you can have a look at the developers guide, containing information like the SDK, 
specs etc. Basicaly everything you'll need to know is in there.

Comment: This PDF can also be of help: http://edu.casio.com/products/fx9860g2/data/fx-9860GII_Soft_E.pdf

Comment: Thanks you both! Fortunatly it says SDK supports C  ;)